# Where to save app info to survive reinstallation after building?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently use `App.Current.Properties` dictionary to save some basic data needed for the app to connect to a database.

Unfortunately, when building and reinstalling the app on the Android simulator (didn't tried on the iOS one), app data seems to be wiped, so every time I test the app I've to re-enter connection info.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you should want to. As a user, when I uninstall an app, I want everything to be gone. And I'm pretty sure that is at least what iOS will do. If this is made possible, every developer will want to leave something behind on my phone and pretty soon my phone runs out of diskspace because of stuff apps leave behind that even aren't installed anymore. Of course, this is a bit exaggerated but I hope you see the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: If you are just cycling between debug sessions, then enable "Preserve data/cache between application deployments" in the Visual Studio/Xamarin Android settings.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis You're absolutely right about uninstallation of apps. But I think this should work as an app update, not reinstallation. You can understand I can't debug this way, if the app starts new every time I start it!

Comment: @SushiHangover Unfortunately, that was already checked and seems it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @Teejay As long as you are not doing complete rebuilds, (i.e. clean/build) and just a build/run it should work as VS is using an `adb install -r` with that option enabled.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be a random behavior. It happens some time, but not all the times.

Comment: @SushiHangover It is possible I've occasionally done a rebuild.

Comment: @Teejay I thought you meant in a production version on a device, not debugging. Sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you start the app without redeploying it? If you just click the app icon on the emulator. If it does not you have propbarly forgot to call the save method.

```
Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```